# Xamarin.Forms HttpWebResponse Hangs / Freezes

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, httpwebrequest

I got a problem with my `HttpWebResponse` object inside my `Task<T>`

```
public async Task<string> Get(string url)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(urlAddress);
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);

        Debug.WriteLine($"CHECKING 5000");

        using (var resp = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"CHECKING 10000");

            if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                //var json = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                //status = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyResultObject>(json);

                Debug.WriteLine($"CHECKING = {resp.StatusCode}");
            }
        }
    }

    return "";
}
```

I have a number of `Debug.WriteLine()`'s is here to easily see what part my code gets to.

I can see **Debug.WriteLine($"CHECKING 5000");**
I cannot see **Debug.WriteLine($"CHECKING 10000");**

I can access the website in a browser fine, so I am not sure what the issue here.

What can I do to see why it is doesn't work and then fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
public async Task<string> Get(string url)
{

    Debug.WriteLine($"CHECKING 5000");

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"CHECKING 10000");

        var resp = await client.GetAsync (url);

        //you can replace the if below with response.IsSuccessStatusCode
        if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"CHECKING = {resp.StatusCode}");
        }

    }

    return String.Empty;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the fix - sorry couldn't reply sooner. Had to sleep :-)

Comment: Just a quick tip, you shouldn't create an HttpClient each time you do a web request, more info here https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/